# Websphere 6.1 - Configuring Security

Tags: security, websphere, websphere-6.1

When i try to configure security through the admin console of Websphere it just hangs.
Its at the last step of the below 4 steps

1. Specify extent of protection
2. Select user repository
3. Configure user repository
4. Summary

Here are the extracts from my console

```
[26/09/08 13:50:56:539 IST] 0000001f ServletWrappe I   
    SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/com.ibm.ws.console.security/EnableSecurity.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[26/09/08 13:50:58:616 IST] 0000001f ServletWrappe I   
    SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/com.ibm.ws.console.security/SelectRegistry.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[26/09/08 13:51:00:126 IST] 0000001f ServletWrappe I   
    SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/com.ibm.ws.console.security/ConfigureRegistry.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[26/09/08 13:51:00:126 IST] 0000001f ServletWrappe I   
    SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/com.ibm.ws.console.security/LocalRegistry.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[26/09/08 13:51:36:202 IST] 0000001f ServletWrappe I   
    SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/com.ibm.ws.console.security/ConfirmEnableSecurity.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[26/09/08 13:52:20:255 IST] 0000001f UserRegistryI A   
    SECJ0136I: Custom Registry:com.ibm.ws.security.registry.nt.NTLocalDomainRegistryImpl has been initialized
[26/09/08 13:52:21:025 IST] 0000001f UserRegistryI A   
    SECJ0136I: Custom Registry:com.ibm.ws.security.registry.nt.NTLocalDomainRegistryImpl has been initialized
[26/09/08 14:04:03:127 IST] 00000019 ThreadMonitor W   
    WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 2" (0000001f) has been active for 746076 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
```

Any idea what could be up here?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like your LDAP server is not responding in a timely manor.  The fact that you have a hung thread rather than a network error indicates to me that you are successfully communicating to LDAP.  If you are attaching this to the Active Directory backed LDAP, it could be overtaxed.  We have used [ADAM servers](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/adam/default.mspx) in the past to get around slow LDAP response time.  However our responce times were around 3-5 seconds instead of 12+ minutes.  This could also be a deadlock.  I have seen hung threads as a result of implementing XD extensions where the nodes deadlocked their communication (But these were not WebContainer threads).  To fix this issue, we ditched XD extensions in favor of a [NetScaler](http://www.citrix.com/english/ps2/products/product.asp?contentID=21679) setup.